# How to format numbers with thin space as a thousand separator?

Tags: php, number-formatting, multibyte

Instead of displaying numbers formatted like this:

1,234,567.890, I want to display numbers formatted like this:

1 234 567.890, which is slightly different from this: 
1 234 567.890.

I am using the PHP function:

```
number_format($value, 0, ".", " ")
```

But, it produces this:

1�234�567.890

I have already set the http header and the html document to UTF-8. I believe this problem arises due to the thin space being a multi-byte character. I have not been able to find a mb string function that deals with this.

Does anyone has an idea of how to deal with this problem?

Comment: *"5.4.0 This function now supports multiple bytes in dec_point and thousands_sep. Only the first byte of each separator was used in older versions."* - Yes, seems like you'll have to roll your own implementation (or upgrade PHP).

Comment: Are you sure that this code doesn't work right : `number_format(1234567890, 0, '.', ' ');`

Comment: @deceze, Ah.. nice. I see.. Thanks, I will need an upgrade then.

Comment: You can also see the results in different versions of PHP here: http://3v4l.org/mKqfT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 5.4.0 This function now supports multiple bytes in dec_point and thousands_sep. Only the first byte of each separator was used in older versions.
>
> http://php.net/number_format

Based on that, here's a very hacky fix for the problem in older PHP versions, short of rolling your own implementation of `number_format`:

```
$separator = ' ';
echo preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\x' . bin2hex($separator[0]) . '(?=\d)/',
                  $separator,
                  number_format($value, 0, '.', $separator));
```

Comment: You are always such a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

In newer (>5.4.0) versions of PHP, just use the thin space as a separator directly, like this:

```
number_format($value, 0, ".", "&thinsp;");
```